# Secure generic .asp / asp.net app w Google Authenticator at IIS level: possible?

Tags: iis

We have a couple of apps we run (that we did not write) on IIS.

We would like to make access restricted via 2 factor.

Possible?

(In my dreams, I could set it up at the IIS application level... using google authenticator)

(Or is the only way to put em behind vpn?)

Comment: Without touching those apps, it should be possible to write an IIS module to achieve what you desire. But I did not see anyone created one so you will have to do it yourself.

Comment: @LexLi Can you elaborate? I do not follow you (yet)